# Declaring variable name with string and number?

Tags: python, declaration

Is there any way to declare a variable name string with number while running a loop? How can I do that? For example given `n1, n2, n3...`, `n1` has to store `i+l` value(`n("string")` with `i("number")` = n1) then `n2` has to stored `i+l` value of iterated loop.....etc

```
i=0
l=1
K=range(2,10)
for i in K:
    print i
    #how to declare a variable name by concatenating string and number
    print '--------',l+i
    #print n1,n2.....etc
```

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-to-a-while-loop ?

Comment: Do not try to dynamically name variables.  Use a `dict` if you have key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list like such...

```
n = []
for i in k:
    n.append(some_value)
```

then, instead of n1, you could access each variable with n[0], n[1]...

(you could also use a dictionary if you needed more flexibility on index numbers...

```
n = {}
for i in k:
    n[i] = some_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that this is a Very Bad Idea, yes, you can do it.

```
def fun():
    name = "n"
    for i in range(4):
        exec '%s%d = %d'%(name, i, 2**i)
    print n0
    print n1
    print n2
    print n3

fun()
```